# removing event listener inside for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I'm trying to remove the event listener that I've added to my `UL`; so that the listener function will only fire on the first click and will be cleared after that.

Is there a way to do this with pure js?

```
 var cardDeck = document.getElementById('listDeck').getElementsByTagName('li')

    for (var i = 0; i < cardDeck.length; i++) {
      cardDeck[i].addEventListener('click', flip, false)
    }

    function flip(e) {
      if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
      var firstMove = document.getElementById(e.target.id)
      firstMove.classList.add('open', 'show')
        console.log(e.target.id + 'card was clicked');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add option of {Once :true} to event listener. No need to write a code for it.Just try these

```
cardDeck[i].addEventListener('click', flip, {once:true} )
```

Here's the jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/oum0c7jn/6/)

Reference link for this.[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

PS: 
The way you are adding evenListener to every element is not efficient. Use delegation instead of bubbling if possible for your use case.Here's fiddle for [delegation](https://jsfiddle.net/jm1x4755/)

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I think you're right. It looks like because I'm adding an individual event listener to each list element - I'm not getting the desired effect of clicking on one card and clearing the event. I'm going to try and add the event handler to the parent element and go from there

Comment: Check delegation link. It's on parent

Comment: Anytime brother!

Comment: Wow... what an answer should get 999k up

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to the `onclick` method instead of using the `addEventListener`. Thus, after the click is performed just set `onclick` to `null`:

```
var cardDeck = document.getElementById('listDeck').getElementsByTagName('li')

for (var i = 0; i < cardDeck.length; i++) {
  cardDeck[i].onclick = flip.bind(cardDeck[i])
}

function flip(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
    var firstMove = document.getElementById(e.target.id)
    firstMove.classList.add('open', 'show')
    console.log(e.target.id + 'card was clicked');
    this.onclick = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just gave this a try. Looks like multiple clicks still add the new classes to the cards

Answer (score 0):

If you added an event handler via `addEventListener`, you can remove it using:

```
element.removeEventListener(event, function);
```

This allows you to selectively remove event handlers and not remove any other handlers that may have been registered.

```
function flip(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        var firstMove = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
        firstMove.classList.add('open', 'show');
        console.log(e.target.id + 'card was clicked');
        e.currentarget.removeEventListener('click', flip);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an event listener when it is called, you can use the `removeEventListener` on the DOM element like so :

```js
 var cardDeck = document.getElementById('listDeck').getElementsByTagName('li')

    for (var i = 0; i < cardDeck.length; i++) {
      cardDeck[i].addEventListener('click', flip, false)
    }

    function flip(e) {
    //remove the event listener.
    this.removeEventListener("click",flip);
      if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
      var firstMove = document.getElementById(e.target.id)
      firstMove.classList.add('open', 'show')
        console.log(e.target.id + 'card was clicked');
      }
    }
```